# С чего начать изучение програмирования?

Tags: c++, c

Не языки, а основы, принципы, книги посоветуйте.

Comment: Бери и пробуй.

Answer (score 1):

Программирование надо начинать учить с английского =)

Comment: Чтобы начать, хватит информации и на русском. Английский нужен уже для углубленного изучения, чтобы изучить ту информацию, которую нельзя найти на русском языке. Конечно, он пригодится, чтобы грамотно называть переменные и функции.

 Я считаю, что для программирования вполне хватит знаний школьной программы английского языка + словарь для незнакомых слов. Технические тексты намного легче воспринимаются, чем художественные, и особых знаний грамматики не потребуется.

Answer (score 0):

Основы и принципы? Ты их изучишь, когда займешься языком программирования. 
Есть хорошая книга Р.Лафоре "Объектно ориентированное программирование в С++".

Answer (score 0):

Не вижу смысла изучать пустые принципы программирования. Если ты не знаешь ни одного языка, то вряд ли что-то поймёшь. Принципы программирования изучаются вместе с языком. После изучения языка уже можно изучить некоторые хитрости (которые в C++ чаще всего бывают "костылями") и паттерны проектирования (например, по книге А. Александреску "Современное проектирование на C++").

Answer (score 0):

Рекомендую вначале получить неплохое базовое образование по какому либо языку на курсах в http://www.INTUIT.ru  ( это "Интернет Университет" - порядка 12-17 тем с зачетами в любом из курсов )и если хватит настроя это сделать, значит Вы наш человек.

Answer (score 0):

Я решил вторым языком изучить чистый Си, так  что куплю двухтомник ["Практика и теория программирования"](http://www.ozon.ru/context/detail/id/5039902/).  Содержание второго тома можете здесь посмотреть, думаю, этого вполне достаточно для начала.

Comment: @Angry Bird ссылка со слова "здесь" не идет куда надо, баг? (я почему и распаковал её полностью)

Answer (score 0):

Могу Вам дать хороший совет: перед тем как читать какую-то книгу - почитайте о ней отзывы, посмотрите рейтинги, например, на Amazon. А вообще как порекомендовали тут: начинать лучше с Таненбаума, Виниера. По C++ рекомендую Лафоре, потом два тома Эккеля Философия C++, потом Скотт Мейерс: его три книги Effective C++ etc (мой любимый автор), Саттера. Конечно же читать, но позже Фаулера.